# Rounding numbers of a CSV file, skipping the header

Tags: perl, numeric-data, arithmetic

This question is a derivative of the https://askubuntu.com/questions/601149/is-there-a-command-to-round-decimal-numbers-in-txt-files, which was successfully solved by using:

```
perl -i -pe 's/(\d*\.\d*)/int($1+0.5)/ge' file
```

The problem is, the header of my CSV file is also modified by the perl's oneliner above, which is inconvenient for me. Is there any way to skip the first line or row of the CSV file in this oneliner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl has a special variable `$.` that keeps track of the current line number. So you can add a simple conditional `$. > 1` to the substitution:

```
perl -i -pe 's/(\d*\.\d*)/int($1+0.5)/ge if $. > 1' file
```

See [PerlVar: Variables related to filehandles](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles)

---

Other tools have explicit header handling ex. with `numfmt` from GNU Coreutils:

```
numfmt -d, --header --format='%.0f' --field=- --invalid=ignore <file
```

(rounding is IEEE from-zero by default).

Comment: It works great! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for `numfmt`! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to retain the header in the output:

```
$ cat file
number
0.1
1.2
3.8
```

```
$ awk 'NR > 1 { $0 = sprintf("%d", $0 + 0.5) }; 1' file
number
0
1
4
```

This uses `awk` to reformat the numbers in the data in the same sort of way that your Perl one-liner does, but without touching the first line.

For each line of the input, apart from the first, the number is rounded and the line is rewritten with the modified data.  The trailing `1` in the code causes all lines, whether modified or not, to be outputted.